# Is it possible to get the entity from SQLAlchemys "do_orm_execute" event?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We're trying to implement a History table for some select classes. All the queries are written for SQLAlchemy Core 1.x and passed to the `execute()` method on the `Session` object. That means we cannot use the more straight forward events such as "before_flush".

According to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_events.html#session-execute-events) we should be able to access the type that is a target for an `insert()`, `update()` or `delete()`

But that just throws `AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'column_descriptions'` (I'm guessing it's either due to it only being available on selects or only if the query originated from the ORM)

All the tables are declared in a file generated from sqlacodegen without any declarative base, like so:

```
t_example = Table(
    'examples', metadata,
    Column('id', UUID, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', Text, nullable=False),
)
```

Now we've newly migrated to SQLAlchemy 2.0 and implemented asyncio, implemented a declarative_base but since thousands of queries are written directly towards tables like:

```
query = select(t_example.c.name).where(
        t_example.c.id == some_id
    )
```

And we don't want to spend weeks updating them but slowly migrating the tables to classes like so:

```
class Example(Base, LogInsertMixin, LogUpdateMixin, LogDeleteMixin):
    __table__ = t_example
    id: Mapped[UUID]
    name: Mapped[str]
```

As you can see we have some mixins that I thought could be declared on the models that require some logging to the database:

```
class LogInsertMixin:
    pass


class LogUpdateMixin:
    pass


class LogDeleteMixin:
    pass
```

But I can't find any way in the "do_orm_execute" event to make an `isistance()` check toward:

```
class DatabaseLogger:

    def orm_execute_event(self, orm_execute_state: ORMExecuteState):
        if orm_execute_state.is_update and isinstance(*****what to check for? :(*****, LogUpdateMixin):
            pass
```

I can see that the event fires but `ORMExecuteState` isn't well documented. Is this way even feasible? How can I find out what `Table()` was passed to an `update()` or `delete()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone falling into this rabbit hole I found the solution.

`orm_execute_state` has a property `statement` which is an `Executable`, in my case it will be either a construct of `Select`, `Delete`, `Update` or `Insert`.

On those construts we can access `entity_description` which contains the mapping:

```
class DatabaseLogger:

def orm_execute_event(self, orm_execute_state: ORMExecuteState):
    if orm_execute_state.is_update and isinstance(
        orm_execute_state.statement, Update
    ): # isinstance to tell vscode to give correct code hints
        print(
            orm_execute_state.statement.entity_description
        )
```

Results in:

> {'name': 'Example', 'type': <class 'Example'>, 'expr': <class
> 'Example'>, **'entity': <class 'Example'>**, **'table': Table('t_example'**,
> MetaData(), Column('id', UUID(), table=<t_example>, primary_key=True,
> nullable=False,
> server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause
> object at 0x7fbcd020d7c0>, for_update=False)), Column('name', Text(),
> table=<t_example>))}